# Is it possible to empty a map's contents without the containing objects' destructors being called?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a `map` I am using to quickly access some elements on my program. I want to remove some of these elements from my `map` (I have references to them elsewhere). Is there some way to remove these items without having their destructors called by the `map`'s `clear()` or `erase()` functions?

Comment: What is your actual goal?  What's bad about having the destructors called?

Comment: I am treating the map as an index for my greater program. When I no longer need the items in that index, I still need them in other parts of the program.

Comment: Then you ought to use pointers of some kind as the mapped type.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing, however, as soon as I call the clear() function, my program crashes. With a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: Sounds like you may be inadvertently accessing a non-existent key value (perhaps after a `clear`), which will default-construct and return an element - in this case, an uninitialized (or null) pointer, either of which will kill you if you try and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're mapping pointers to the objects, the objects themselves won't be destroyed.  If the objects themselves are in the map, they will be destroyed.

Comment: I am mapping <int, Object*>. It seems as though the Object*s are being destroyed.

Comment: The pointers to Object are destroyed, then, but not the pointed-to Objects.  It sounds like something is wrong or confused.

Comment: Are you adding `std::auto_ptr<Object>` or some other kind of smart pointer? If not, the destructor of the pointed-to object shouldn't be called (the pointer itself, of course, will be destroyed).

Answer (score 2):

Use shared_ptr, that's what it's for. If the items are stored "definitively" elsewhere, consider using weak_ptr in the map, and shared_ptr for the definitive store location.

There are probably other methods which *could* work, but save yourself a headache and use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If the elements are stored by-value, there is no way to do so. If you need that capability, consider putting them into smart pointers (like `unique_ptr` that allows you to `.release()` the held pointer).

Answer (score 0):

No; the only standard container with a `splice()` method is `std::list`. That means you can move list nodes from one list to another, but not map or set nodes.

Answer (score 0):

What we've heard so far is that you have a container where the values are pointers.  I'm assuming the keys are trivial types like integers, or maybe std::strings.  And you say your program "crashes" when you call map<>::clear().  This suggests you have some sort of memory corruption prior to the clear() call, because I can see no reason why clearing simple value types would crash.

Try running your program under valgrind to detect memory access errors.  You probably have one.